# Java converts long to int

Tags: java, int, long-integer

The following code:

```
 import java.util.*;

 public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    long N = s.nextLong();
    long[] arr = new long[N];
    
    System.out.println(N);
    
 }
}
```

Getting this error:

```
HelloWorld.java:12: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from long to int long[] arr = new long[N];
```

As far as I understand there is no int involved in the code, can anyone explain why this is happening and how to solve this issue?

Comment: Array sizes are defined using `int`s, so in `... = new long[N]`, the compiler tries to convert the value of `long N` to an `int`-value. Since this conversion may loose precision, no automatic conversion is performed and instead a compile time error is generated. Define `N` as `int` and read an `int` instead, and you should be good to go. --- As an aside: variable names in java should always start with a lowercase letter (`long N = ...;` -> `long n = ...;`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size of arrays in Java can not exceed the range of an `int`, so the size parameter for array creation is implicitly an `int`. Change `N` to an `int`.

From [JLS 15.10.1 Array Creation Expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.1) (emphasis mine):

> Each dimension expression undergoes unary numeric promotion (§5.6.1). **The promoted type must be `int`, or a compile-time error occurs.**

Answer (score 2):

Array subscripts and sizes in Java must always be `int`, so in this expression `new long[N]` the `N` is converted to `int`, and because `long` has wider range than `int`, it's a narrowing conversion which must be done explicitly: `new long[(int) N]`. Or just read `N` as `int`: `int N = s.nextInt()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
long[] arr = new long[N];
```

In this line you are creating an array of size N, but array sizes in Java can only be integers, that's why it's reading N as an int, if your intent is creating an array of N size you should read N as an int

```
int N = s.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

The maximum length of an array in java is 2,147,483,647 (2^31 - 1) which is the maximum length of int. So implicitly an array can have maximum the value of an int. So it cannot accept a long number.